# C# - Enforce Child Object Immutability in Struct

Tags: c#, struct, immutability

I am trying to create an immutable struct. The problem is, it contains mutable objects inside. Is it possible to make those immutable (without modifying their class)? For example (https://dotnetfiddle.net/KTiTzB):

```
public class IntHolder
{
    public int X
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public struct ImmutableStruct
{
    public int ImmutableInt
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IntHolder MyIntHolder
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ImmutableStruct(int immutableInt, IntHolder myIntHolder): this ()
    {
        ImmutableInt = immutableInt;
        MyIntHolder = myIntHolder;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Immutability");
        IntHolder intHolder = new IntHolder();
        intHolder.X = 40;
        Console.WriteLine(intHolder.X == 40); // TRUE
        ImmutableStruct immStruct = new ImmutableStruct(10, intHolder);
        Console.WriteLine(immStruct.ImmutableInt == 10); // TRUE
        // immStruct.ImmutableInt = 4; // THIS DOESN'T WORK, AS EXPECTED. Hurray!
        // immStruct.MyIntHolder = new IntHolder(3); // ALSO DOESN'T WORK, GOOD!
        immStruct.MyIntHolder.X = 4; // how can I prevent this from working?
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the IntHolder member immutable while leaving the IntHolder class unmodified?

Comment: Decorator Pattern maybe (e.g. extension methods)?

Comment: Can you make the class implement an interface?

Comment: I'm not sure, but possibly.

Comment: I think the short answer is no. Think about, I declare a type `A`, it describes itself a mutable. I declare another type, type `B`, that exposes a member of type `A`. That member has to be mutable if its type `A`, if its not mutable, its not type `A`.

Comment: I suppose it could be possible to create a kind of one off "cookie cutter" factory that could take a mutable type and create an immutable facsimile of it. You could allow for the implicit casting of the facsimile into a new instance of the mutable type (if you can access the constructor.) The facsimile could have equality operators for the mutable type. However the facsimile would not be "of" the mutable type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a big question: how to handle nested objects in immutable data?

1. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279580/how-to-make-complex-objects-immutable
2. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5
3. https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/immutableupdatepatterns

In my opinion, It's worthy to create immutable children models to make sure the whole object immutable.

See comments in code below:

```
public class IntHolder
{
    public int X
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ImmutableIntHolder ToImmutable()//convert itself to ImmutableIntHolder 
    {
        return new ImmutableIntHolder(X);
    }
}
public class ImmutableIntHolder
{
    public ImmutableIntHolder(int x)
    {
        X = x;
    }
    public int X
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IntHolder ToIntHolder() //convert it back to mutable IntHolder 
    {
        return new IntHolder()
        {
            X = this.X
        };
    }
}
public struct ImmutableStruct
{
    public int ImmutableInt
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ImmutableIntHolder IntHolder //use ImmutableIntHolder instead
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ImmutableStruct(int immutableInt, IntHolder myIntHolder) : this()
    {
        ImmutableInt = immutableInt;
        IntHolder = myIntHolder.ToImmutable(); // convert to immutable
    }
}
```

another option is:

```
public class IntHolder
{
    public int X
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public class ImmutableStruct //changed to class
{
    public int ImmutableInt
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ImmutableIntHolder IntHolder
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ImmutableStruct(int immutableInt, IntHolder myIntHolder) //: this()
    {
        ImmutableInt = immutableInt;
        IntHolder = new ImmutableIntHolder(myIntHolder); // convert here.
    }

    public class ImmutableIntHolder
    {
        public ImmutableIntHolder(IntHolder intHolder)
        {
            //map all properties
            X = intHolder.X;
        }
        public int X
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I came up with another solution, but I'm not sure it is good: (https://dotnetfiddle.net/ChRVjr). I put a copy constructor in the IntHolder and just had the ImmutableStruct return the copy. Thoughts?

Comment: @Jeff `private IntHolder MyIntHolder` is inaccessible, which is not good. and  `IntHolder GetIntHolder()` always returns a shadow copy on every call, which is not good, too. I think it is same with this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uaWX0l, which is not good as well.